# Excel count if relative reference

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, reference

I want to count number of occurrences for items listed in column A only IF the numbers in column B are greater than 0. In column E, I would like to have the results, that is # of occurrences for items listed in column A, counted only if corresponding number in Column B is greater than 0. I have over a thousand of items in column A. I have put the results I would like to see in column E.

Please select this link (or copy and paste to a web browser) to view this excel in a web browser in case the image I added does not display.

[image]

I tried different things but cannot make it work.

Comment: To be clear, you have your table in A:B, and in column E:D you want to have the items that have more than 0 occurrences to appear and the count of those occurrences?

Comment: I have removed the link of screenshot and took screenshot to post. Please dont post any foreign links in the post. Also you have deleted your last similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78116607/8162520) which was already edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `COUNTIFS()` function:

[image]

---

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A9,C2:C5,B2:B9,">0")
```

---

If it has to be dynamic in a way that it has to pull all the data into one single array then how about using one of the following:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Data, A2:B9,
     _Fruits, TAKE(_Data,,1),
     _ListedCounts, TAKE(_Data,,-1),
     _Occurrences, COUNTIFS(_Fruits,_Fruits,_ListedCounts,">0"),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(_Fruits,TEXT(_Occurrences,"[=1]0 \O\c\c\u\r\r\e\n\c\e;0 \O\c\c\u\r\r\e\n\c\e\s"))))
```

---

Or,

[image]

```
=LET(
     _Data, A2:B9,
     _Fruits, TAKE(_Data,,1),
     _ListedCounts, TAKE(_Data,,-1),
     _Occurrences, COUNTIFS(_Fruits,_Fruits,_ListedCounts,">0"),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(_Fruits,_Occurrences,IFS(_Occurrences=1,"Occurrence",TRUE,"Occurrences"))))
```

---

Like I have already posted using `COUNTIFS()` function which is primary function here and does main job, lets explain a bit abt the rest of the functions:

- Using `LET()` function it becomes easier to read and use variables for ranges/functions.
- `_Data` refers to whole of data, usually in the forum we suggest to use `Structured References` instead of using the whole ranges, which slows the excel functionality. Tables makes easier to adjust the ranges automatically by rows/columns. However i have used only the ranges specified. No blank rows taken into account.
- `_Fruit` refers to the fruits columns i.e. `A2:A9` using `TAKE()` function to extract it.
- `_ListedCounts` like wise above used `TAKE()` function to the specific column.
- `_Occurrences` refers to the frequency of the number of times fruits appeared with a value greater than `0`
- Using `UNIQUE()` function to get unique values from the merged data combined using `HSTACK()` of the three arrays `_Fruits`, `_Occurrences` as well as the additional col with specific words as `Occurrence` or `Occurrences` to get the desired output.

---

**Note:** In the second method I have used a custom formula in the `TEXT()` function which uses backslash which is an escape character. It serves a different purpose, we are escaping it meaning hence asking Excel to literally form text with that character.

---

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you need to dynamically get the unique list of items and "occurrence" / "occurrences"

```
=LET(ITEMS,UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"")),
COUNTS,COUNTIFS(A:A,ITEMS,B:B,">"&0),
OCC,IF(COUNTS=1,"occurrence","occurrences"),
HSTACK(ITEMS,COUNTS,OCC))
```

`LET` to define names for the 3 columns you want

`UNIQUE` and `FILTER` to get a list of all possible items from column A

`COUNTIFS` to count how many times those items appear with a number greater than 0

`IF` to determine whether the text in the 3rd column should be singular or plural

`HSTACK` to put those three columns together side by side

[image]